# mysql how to get row position with where clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb, position, row

i have data like this

```
id  userid        phone
1   1000          11111
2   1001          22222
3   1000          33333
4   1000          44444
5   1001          55555
6   1000          66666
```

column phone is unique

i am expecting the following result

```
position phone
3        44444
```

i tried row_number but its not working.

```
select *,row_number() over 
    (partition by userid order by id asc) as position 
from table 
where phone=44444
```

this way position always 1

Comment: Are you interested in the value of `id`? You don't have any sorting in your statement, so there is no guarantee about the order returned.

Comment: `row_number` is applied after WHERE is applied, hence you count the position for a rowset of one row. Use enumeration in CTE and filtering in outer query.

Comment: *i am expecting the following result* For specified `order by id asc` the position for `phone=44444` must be 4, not 3... explain carefully.

Comment: akira , sorry for bad explanation. i meant to ask calculating position based on rows list where userid=userid of phone.

Comment: `select userid from table where phone=44444` will give 1000,  then `select * from table where userid=1000` will give  ``` 1   1000          11111
3   1000          33333
4   1000          44444
6   1000          66666   ```   means 44444 row coming third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` is applied on the result set according to the `WHERE` clause. Since you got only one record in that result, the `row_number()` is `1`.

You first need to select the complete set, apply `row_number()` to it and then get the record with the searched number

```
SELECT position,
       phone
       FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY userid
                                       ORDER BY id ASC) AS position,
                    phone
                    FROM elbat) AS x
       WHERE phone = 44444;
```

If the table is large, it might be beneficial to limit the results of the derived table to the records of the user that has the searched number. An index on `(phone, userid)` and another one on `(userid, id, phone)` might support this.

```
SELECT position,
       phone
       FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS position,
                    phone
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE userid = (SELECT userid
                                           FROM elbat
                                           WHERE phone = 44444)) AS x
       WHERE phone = 44444;
```

Comment: yes.table is very large like 2gb.

Comment: i tried second query it worked.but the execution time is taking long if userid has too many records for example  200k records its taking 8 seconds to finish. do you know what parameter should i look at in mysql conf file?

Comment: @korangu: I made an edit suggesting indexes.

Comment: i already have 2 separate index on userid and phone which occupied 1.2gb storage if i add more index table size will grow even a lot bigger.

Comment: @korangu: So? Of course indexes need space, that's no a problem, disk space is cheap nowadays.

Comment: my server has only 4gb memory. index also need ram?

Comment: @korangu: It doesn't permanently lie in the RAM, unless there's enough space to keep it, but the parts that need to be accessed must be in the RAM, yes, of course. And so do tables. But this develops into a very generic discussion about how DBMS and even computers in general work, which is out of scope for the question and a very broad field in general too.